# ASMX Test page displays HTTP POST as option when viewed from local machine but not remotely?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, testing, asmx, http-post

The auto-generated test page displays HTTP POST as option when viewed from local machine but not remotely.

1. Why?
2. How do I get it to display HTTP POST as an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.  You will only get the test page from your local machine.

If you want to see it from remote machines:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/be17cb5f-29c6-40a6-a319-b3ce9a784632/

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify I get the test page, but the HTTP POST example is not displayed and the invoke button is not available.